# jQuery UI Tabs non-functional

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

jQuery UI tabs does not even function, why? I've properly declared the function, applicable external resources loaded. No, it just sits there and does nothing. I had it working before where it would cycle between divs. Now, they just sit as static open divs, not even cycling anymore let alone loaing properly.

What am I trying to do? Get jQuery UI tabs to function again.

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/rnzu8azz/1/

Comment: Any clues in your console/debugger? Are all of your includes there?

Comment: Yeah, Google dev tool says no errors in the console panel.

Comment: jQuery UI and jQuery on page. No duplicates either.

Comment: [working](http://jsfiddle.net/MattSizzle/rnzu8azz/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Just took a look at your fiddle. Your `<ul>` elements need to be inside of your `#tabs` div:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#tabs-1">ONE</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#tabs-2">TWO</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#tabs-3">THREE</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">TESTING 1</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">TESTING 2</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">TESTING 3</div>
</div>
```

Also, you did not include jquery UI in your fiddle.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rnzu8azz/3/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your UL has to be inside the #tabs div:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#tabs-1">ONE</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#tabs-2">TWO</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#tabs-3">THREE</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">TESTING 1</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">TESTING 2</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">TESTING 3</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle One](http://jsfiddle.net/rnzu8azz/5/)

Next, you might wish to use jQueryUI with an earlier version of jQuery -- see the effect in

[jsFiddle Two](http://jsfiddle.net/rnzu8azz/4/)

which uses jQuery 1.9.1 with jQueryUI 1.9.2

Comment: Yup it is an issue with versioning